# OrientDB default OLDAPImporter class missing?

Tags: orientdb

I'm running with OrientDB Community 2.2.3 GA and after reading about some of the new security features of OrientDB introduced since version 2.2.x (http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Security-OrientDB-New-Security-Features.html), I've been attempting to test the new LDAPImporter.

I've updated the security.json file with the "ldapImporter" configuration settings, following the example provided from the Security Configuration documentation (My reputation will not allow me to post a link to it, but you can click on "Security Configuration" from the above link to view).

When I start the OrientDB server now, I get an exception that the OLDAPImporter class is not found.

```
2016-06-28 15:25:16:572 INFO  OSystemUserAuthenticator is active [OSystemUserAuthenticator]ODefaultServerSecurity.getClass() Throwable:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.orientechnologies.security.ldap.OLDAPImporter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.security.ODefaultServerSecurity.getClass(ODefaultServerSecurity.java:129)

    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.security.ODefaultServerSecurity.reloadImportLDAP(ODefaultServerSecurity.java:959)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.security.ODefaultServerSecurity.loadComponents(ODefaultServerSecurity.java:751)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.security.ODefaultServerSecurity.onAfterActivate(ODefaultServerSecurity.java:673)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:392)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)

2016-06-28 15:25:16:587 SEVER ODefaultServerSecurity.reloadImportLDAP() ImportLDAP class property is missing [ODefaultServerSecurity]
2016-06-28 15:25:16:587 INFO  OrientDB Server is active v2.2.3 (build 2.2.x@r2f229613abac00036c2fa1b59ab5d1e8a882d6de; 2016-06-20 06:46:10+0000). [OServer]
```

When I examine the contents of the orientdb-core-2.2.3.jar I do not see a java file that defines the OLDAPImporter class. Further, looking at the 2.2.x branch on GitHub, I also cannot find the source file for the class (Again my current reputation doesn't allow me to post more than 1 link per post, but I'm looking here: .../orientechnologies/orientdb/tree/2.2.x/core/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/security).

The documentation lead me to believe the feature was fully implemented, so I assume I'm just completely missing something obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi The Oldap importer is not in bundle with the community edition.

You can compile it from here

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-security

and install the jar in lib folder

or you can download the Enterprise Edition here that contains that feature.

http://orientdb.com/orientdb-enterprise